# How to save multiple output in multiple file where each file has a different title coming from an object in python?

Tags: python, rss, feed

I'm scraping rss feed from a web site (http://www.gfrvitale.altervista.org/index.php/autismo-in?format=feed&type=rss).
I have wrote down a script to extract and purifie the text from every  of the feed. My main problem is to save each text of each item in a different file, I also need to name each file with it's proper title exctractet from the item.
My code is:

```
for item in myFeed["items"]:
    time_structure=item["published_parsed"]
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time_structure))

    if dt>t:

     link=item["link"]           
     response= requests.get(link)
     doc=Document(response.text)
     doc.summary(html_partial=False)

     # extracting text
     h = html2text.HTML2Text()

     # converting
     h.ignore_links = True  #ignoro i link
     h.skip_internal_links=True  #ignoro i link esterni
     h.inline_links=True
     h.ignore_images=True  #ignoro i link alle immagini
     h.ignore_emphasis=True
     h.ignore_anchors=True
     h.ignore_tables=True

     testo= h.handle(doc.summary())  #testo estratto

     s = doc.title()+"."+" "+testo  #contenuto da stampare nel file finale

     tit=item["title"]

     # save each file with it's proper title
     with codecs.open("testo_%s", %tit "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
         f.write(s)
         f.close()
```

The error is:

```
File "<ipython-input-57-cd683dec157f>", line 34 with codecs.open("testo_%s", %tit "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the comma after `%tit`

should be:

```
#save each file with it's proper title
with codecs.open("testo_%s" %tit, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
     f.write(s)
     f.close()
```

However, if your file name has invalid characters it will return an error (i.e `[Errno 22]`)

You can try this code:

```
...
tit = item["title"]
tit = tit.replace(' ', '').replace("'", "").replace('?', '') # Not the best way, but it could help for now (will be better to create a list of stop characters)

with codecs.open("testo_%s" %tit, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
     f.write(s)
     f.close()
```

Other way using `nltk`:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tit = item["title"]
tit = tokenizer.tokenize(tit)
tit = ''.join(tit)
with codecs.open("testo_%s" %tit, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
     f.write(s)
     f.close()
```

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work, I get this error: C:\Anaconda2\lib\codecs.pyc in open(filename, mode, encoding, errors, buffering)
    894             # Force opening of the file in binary mode
    895             mode = mode + 'b'
--> 896     file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    897     if encoding is None:
    898         return file

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: u'testo_La Comunicazione Facilitata? Parliamone.

Comment: The code is right. The comma is after the target `%tit`, not before. That is another error. I'll check.

Comment: What is the desired output? (i.e. `.csv`, `.txt`)

Comment: Your problem is the name of the string ***u'testo_La Comunicazione Facilitata?..*** You cannot call your file like that. I edited my answer, with one solution for that.

Comment: #estebanpdl with your etit it works much better but i still have some problem on some title. So i try to make more replaces and than i tell you how it goes. Thanks so much!

Comment: @CosimoCuriale Yes! That's why I commented that line. Is better if you create a list of those characters and call them from one function. If you think it works you can check the answer!

Comment: @CosimoCuriale several replaces could take a while. You can use `nltk`. I made another edition with one example.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you misplaced the comma, it should be after the `%tit` not before.

Secondly, you don't need to close the file because the `with` statement that you use, does it automatically for you. And where did the codecs came from? I don't see it anywhere else.... anyway, the correct `with` statement would be:

```
with open("testo_%s" %tit, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
     f.write(s)
```

Comment: I have runned the code above but it gave error. Now  I'm tring this:        with io.open("testo_"+tit, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(s)

Comment: what error does it give? you should provide something to work with...  and for the naming you should stick with the `"testo_%s" %tit` since i don't think that `"testo_"+tit` would work (but i might be just wrong)

Comment: I have runned the code above but it give me error. It say that the function doen't accept %tit like argument. Now  I'm tring this:                               with io.open("testo_"+tit, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(s)      It functions partially because it save the first item with his proper title and than it stops. I get this new error:IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: u'testo_La Comunicazione Facilitata? Parliamone...'